# WordPress search results only showing if admin is logged in

Tags: wordpress, search

WordPress search results only showing if admin is logged in.
I tried deactivating plug-ins and that didn't work. Here is the code from the search.php file (below). Not sure if this is where the problem could be or somewhere else.

If it is in the function.php file:

```php
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package Wowmall
 */

get_header();
$col      = 'col-xl-12';
$post_col = 'col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12';
$template = '';
global $wp_query,$wowmall_options;
if( ! empty( $wowmall_options['blog_layout_type'] ) && ! in_array( $wowmall_options['blog_layout_type'], array( 'grid', 'masonry' ) ) ) {
    $col      = 'col-xl-10 col-lg-9 col-md-8';
    $post_col = 'col-xs-12';
    $template = '-list';
}
?>
<div class="container">

    <header class=page-header>
        <h1 class="page-title page-title-search"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for %s', 'wowmall' ), '<span class=wowmall-search-query-title>&#x27;' . get_search_query() . '&#x27;</span>' ); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .page-header -->
    <div class="row">
        <main id=primary class="content-area site-main <?php echo esc_attr( $col ); ?>">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="row posts-<?php echo count( $wp_query->posts ); ?>">

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_col ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    /**
                     * Run the loop for the search to output the results.
                     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                     * called content-search.php and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', '' );
                    ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text' => '<i class=myfont-left-open-2></i>',
                'next_text' => '<i class=myfont-right-open-2></i>',
                'type'      => 'list',
            ) ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </main>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in if( is_admin ) { //code }

Comment: Your loop is looking for a template file `template-parts/content.php` Does that exist?

Comment: Yes it does 
 <?php?>
<article id=post-<?php the_ID(); ?> <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <?php wowmall_post_thumb();
 if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
  <div class=entry-meta>
   <?php wowmall_post_meta(); ?>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <header class=entry-header>
  <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3 class=entry-title><a href="%s" rel=bookmark>', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); ?>
 </header>

Comment: <div class=entry-content>
  <?php do_action( 'wowmall_post_format_quote' );
  $format = get_post_format();
  if( 'audio' === $format && ! has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
   <div class=post-format-audio__audio>
    <?php do_action( 'wowmall_post_format_audio' ); ?>
   </div>
  <?php }
  the_excerpt(); ?>
 </div>

 <footer class=entry-footer>
  <?php wowmall_entry_footer(); ?>
 </footer>
</article>